# AliExpress API Overseas version prohibits writing

Tags: aliexpress

is anyone managed to register in the AliExpress Developer account - https://developers.aliexpress.com?
I need to use it for dropshipping, so API is needed to manage products.
When I tried to create an account I received an error message: "Overseas version prohibits writing"

[image]

Found an issue on Reddit - https://www.reddit.com/r/Aliexpress/comments/13648j3/developer_api/
I tried using different phone numbers from China, email, etc.
Even asked to register a friend from China, no luck. It seems like a bug.
Also, I tried to contact AliExpress support but was not able to find the right contacts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a question on https://console.aliexpress.com and got an answer from support:

[image]

So, a new website should be used **https://open.aliexpress.com** instead

Not sure why the old one does not have any info about that.

Comment: Hi can you get access with Ukraine Company registration document?